# read csv file with and if condition and print

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv file and print the rows if condition is met.

```
reader = csv.reader(open(csvfile, 'r'))

for row in reader :
    print row
    try:
       (location_id, vrm, valid_datetime) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row if row [0] != '297']
    except:
       print "Error with row: " % row
```

I need only to print row[0] == '295',  but this is  printing all the rows in the files.

Comment: so why do you have condition like `row [0] != '297'`? Why not `row [0] == '295'`

Comment: I have tried that but this is  printing  297 and 295  rows as well

Comment: what's the data in csv like? try using number instead of string i.e. remove quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need only to print row[0] == '295', but this is printing all the rows in the files.

Well yes of course, that's what you ask for:

```
for row in reader :
    print row
```

if you only want to print row(s) matching a given condition you have to test this condition before printing:

```
for row in reader :
    if row[0] != '295':
        continue
    print row
    # etc
```

Note that the condition in your list expression here:

```
(location_id, vrm, valid_datetime) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row if row [0] != '297']
```

is not going to "filter out" rows having `row [0] != '297'` - what it does is actually:

```
decoded = []
for x in row:
    if row[0] != '297':
        decoded.append(x.decode('utf-8-sig'))
```

(location_id, vrm, valid_datetime) = decoded

IOW: if `row[0] != '297', it creates a list of decoded values, else an empty list,  then it tries to unpack the list into`location_id, vrm, valid_datetime`. If`row[0] == '297' the list is empty so the unpacking will fail with `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack` - which you would have found out without your nonsensical try/except block that silences the error message.

IOW, do **not** use bare except clauses, catch expected exceptions (the one you can deal with), and **at least** print the exception message:

```
try:
   (location_id, vrm, valid_datetime) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row]
except exception as e:
   print >> sys.stderr, "Error with row '%s' : %s" % (row, e)
```

A last hint: do not rely on Python closing files, this is not garanteed by the language. Use the `with` construct to make sure your file will be closed whatever happens:

```
with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader :
       # your code here
```